# Max Current Output

Tags: power, current, adapter

Looking around at a couple of power supplies that I own such as a guitar pedal adapter that says it puts out 9V and 1700mA max, how does a power supply like this work so that it doesn't put out too much current and blow up what's attached? There isn't a switch that I physically have to switch but how does the adapater "know" how much current to put out?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a duplicate. The device which is using the power only consumes as much as it 'needs'. So as long as the *voltage* of the power supply and device match, then the device won't be blown up by a bigger current capacity power supply. An under-powered power supply could be damaged by a device which wants more current than it cold supply, though typically power supplies are designed to protect themselves.

Comment: Oh what I was moreso asking though was how the device worked and not how current output is determined. But thank you though for trying to point me to the answer (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adapter is *fixed voltage*. The load resistance (guitar pedal in this case) *sets the current level*. The indication of the output current value refers to the maximum that the adapter can deliver, if the load as needed.

Remember the Ohm's Law

$$
I = \dfrac{V}{R}
$$

For a fixed voltage \$V\$, the load \$R\$ sets the value of \$I\$. An improved adapter or a power supply, can implement a current limiter, wich senses the output current and reduces the output voltage to get a current reduction.